# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error when reading Azure SQLDB from Apache Spark Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, azure-sql-database, databricks

I answered one of my previous questions, however, having fixed the issue, I am faced with an another issue regarding SQLServerException.

I am trying to read in data on an Azure SQLDB.
I have successfully authenticated to the server however when I try to apply the function to read in data I get the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
> '5'

The following is more details on the error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3741352302548628> in readFromDb(processId, query)
      3   try:
----> 4     jdbcDF = (spark.read
      5       .format("jdbc")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    209         else:
--> 210             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    211 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name
```

The code is as follows:

```
def readFromDb(processId, query):
  try:
    jdbcDF = (spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net;database={DBDatabase}")
      .option("user", DBUser)
      .option("query", query)
      .option("password", DBPword)
      .load()    
     )
    return jdbcDF
  except Exception as e:
    writeToLogs(processId,LogType.Error, EventType.FailReadFromDb, LogMessage.FailReadFromDb, errorType = ErrorType.FailReadFromDb)
    raise Error(f"{LogMessage.FailReadFromDb.value} ERROR: {e}")
  except:
    writeToLogs(processId,LogType.FailReadFromDb, EventType.FailReadFromDb, LogMessage.FailReadFromDb, errorType = ErrorType.FailReadFromDb)
    raise Error(f"{LogMessage.FailReadFromDb.value}")
```

Can someone let me know what the code generally means and best approach to fix it?

Comment: perhaps your query has a syntax error?

Comment: most probably that is an error in the query

Comment: @Patterson, did you check the query and resolved the error?

Comment: Yes I did. It would appear the problem was with the query as suggested by @mck and Alex Ott

Comment: @Patterson glad to hear that. Do you need I  post it as answer and end this question?

Comment: @LeonYue, yes, please post it as an answer and end the question. Thanks

Comment: @Patterson you're welcome. You can accept it now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mac and Alex Ott said, the error is mostly caused by the query statements.

And we are glad to hear the error is resolved bye modify the query.